# Wordpress Multisite: Subsites are getting the main site name

Tags: wordpress

My multisite worked fine, but suddenly it does not load the names of the subsites. Instead it displays only the name of the main site.

I tried to disable plugins, reinstall WP etc. Maybe it is caused by 4.6.1?

When I go to /wp-admin/options-general.php of each subsite I see the name of the main site. The blog description is shown properly. When I try to rename the subsite name and save it, it does not change.

Interesting: When I go wp-admin/network/sites.php and look at the settings for each subsite, I can see that the proper names for each subsite.

The problem affects even the get_bloginfo(‘name’); function. It shows the main site name only.

I hope you can help me!

Comment: have you define this code in your config file define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an outdated version of the WPML plugin. Installed a new one and works now.